# libcql example using prepare/execute to manipulate blob data

Tags: cassandra, cql

I am desperately looking for a libcql code snippet that uses prepare/execute to insert and retrieve non-trivial data including a blob.

The demo is great but only performs a trivial adhoc query.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

The response to https://github.com/mstump/libcql/issues/42 helped me a great deal.